# How to use httpclient params and httpclient headers in httpclient post method?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I want to migrate my angular project from angular 5 to angular 7 and for that, I want to convert my all HTTP calls to httpclient call.

Comment: I will keep my fingers crossed for you!

Comment: Please check https://angular.io/guide/http as a general HttpClient documentation. Also check Stack Overflow FAQ https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What are you waiting for, go ahead and start converting FTW!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers. In this question, you haven't demonstrated what you've tried to fix your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Could you plz, write code. Or give a codesandbox - example. 
You could use interceptor, for default header.

some example

```
 getPrices(country: string, items: string, currency: string = ''): Observable<any> {
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('country', country.toUpperCase())
      .set('items', items)
      .set('currency', currency.toUpperCase());
    return this.customHttpHandler.request('GET',
      `${ this.priceApiUrl }/example`,
      new PriceInterceptor(this.exampleService),
      {
        params
      }
    ).pipe(
      catchError(() => of([])),
      retry(2),
      timeout(50000)
    );
  }
```

One more example:

```
export class HttpService{

    constructor(private http: HttpClient){ }

    //http://localhost:60489/Home/PostUser  ASP.NET MVC
    //http://localhost:8080/angular/setUser.php     PHP
    // http://localhost:60820/api/post
    postData(user: User){

        const myHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'my-auth-token'),;

        return this.http.post('http://localhost:60820/api/values', user, {headers:myHeaders}); 
    }
}
```